# Creating dynamic if statements without eval

Tags: php

There is a system that scrapes other site and a user can get information about what was scraped. User should be able to create a filter based on the scraped content (assuming its integer): skip the result if the content is less/greater/equal than a specific user required number and etc. So PHP should be able to check these things, in other words: create a statement with checks if the scraped result is valid too selected filter or not.

Example:

Here we can see an excel table with random numbers (just like a scraped website):
[image]

The user creates and filters that exclude numbers by some filter (same example excel filter):
[image]

The system gets the filter and filters the results:

[image]

Now I need to that same thing just with PHP. I was thinking about eval but it's disabled on my PHP.

PHP example:

```
// the content which was scraped
$scrapedResults = [1, 10, 11, 1216, 15, 55, 556, 123, 225, -15,];

// the user created filters
$filters = [
    ['filter' => ['more' => 0], 'operator' => null,],
    ['filter' => ['less' => 15], 'operator' => 'and'],
    ['filter' => ['equal' => 1216], 'operator' => 'or'],
];

// the filter checker
function isValid(string $action, int $ruleArgument, int $target): bool
{
    switch ($action)
    {
        case 'more': return $ruleArgument > $target;
        case 'less': return $ruleArgument < $target;
        case 'equal': return $ruleArgument === $target;

        default: throw new InvalidArgumentException('unknown action given');
    }
}

$result = [];

foreach ($scrapedResults as $scrapedResult) {
    foreach ($filters as $filter) {
        // how to check with all of these filter clauses?
    }

    // by static this function shoud look like this:
    // if($target > 0 && $target < 15 || $tager === 1216) { return true; } else { return false; }
    // but how I should it created dynamically??
}
```

Another PHP example:

```
// the filter which user created:
$filters = [
    ['filter' => ['more' => 1], 'operator' => null,],
    ['filter' => ['less' => 15], 'operator' => 'and'],
    ['filter' => ['equal' => 1216], 'operator' => 'or'],
    ['filter' => ['equal' => 225], 'operator' => 'or'],
];

// the if clause which my code should generate:
// if($target > 1 && $target < 15 || $target === 1216 || $target === 225) {return true;} else {return false;}
```

There is a twist on this task. In the excel filter is limited to 4 additional filters. The system doesn't have any limits so I can be from 1 to 100000.

In short: I need to find a way to create if dynamic statements in PHP without EVAL()

Any suggestions about logic improvement on this task are welcomed too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented this using closures, there are a set of arrays which define the callback functions used for both the filter types and the operators.

Each time a filter is applied, it first checks the filter is OK, then uses `array_filter()` with the corresponding callback from the lookup table to check each item against the value being filtered by.  Once the whole list of numbers is filtered it then works out how to combine these results with the previous results. Again a callback knows the logic for this part...

```
// the content which was scraped
$scrapedResults = [1, 10, 11, 1216, 15, 55, 556, 123, 225, -15,];

// the user created filters
$filters = [
    ['filter' => ['more' => 0], 'operator' => null,],
    ['filter' => ['less' => 15], 'operator' => 'and'],
    ['filter' => ['equal' => 1216], 'operator' => 'or'],
];

// Implementation of the filters
$filterType = ['more' => function ($a, $b) { return $a > $b; },
    'less' => function ($a, $b) { return $a < $b; },
    'equal' => function ($a, $b) { return $a == $b; }];

// Implementation of the operators
$operators = ['and' => function ($old, $result ) {
                            return array_intersect($old, $result);
                        },
                'or' => function ($old, $result ) {
                            return array_merge($old, $result);
                        }];

$output = [];
foreach ( $filters as $filter ) {
    $currentType = array_keys($filter['filter'])[0];
    if ( !isset($filterType[$currentType]) ) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('unknown action given');
    }
    $filterValue = $filter['filter'][$currentType];
    $callback = $filterType[$currentType];
    $filterRes = array_filter($scrapedResults, function ($a) 
                            use ($callback, $filterValue) {
                    return $callback($a, $filterValue);
                });
    
    if ( $filter['operator'] == null )  {
        $output = $filterRes;
    }
    else if ( isset($operators[$filter['operator']]) )   {
        $output = $operators[$filter['operator']]($output, $filterRes);
    }
}
echo "output->";
print_r($output);
```

This outputs...

```
output->Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 11
    [3] => 1216
)
```